# Docker swarm mode, portainer, traefik

Tags: traefik, docker-swarm-mode, socat, portainer, consul-kv

i'm trying to setup a webserver into Docker Swarm mode. Any help is appreciated.

My idea is to have a single machine configured, to run standalone for now, but ready to scale for load-balance and fault-tollerance purposes.
I expect that traefik run on all my nodes and not only into master, as i have seen in some example.

Current problems:

- Let's encrypt seem don't work, but i can't see error into logs
- I can't reach portainer throw traefik

Another question is if it's possible to use docker swarm integrated Key/Value instead of Consul

My deploying file below:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  # swarm_socket
  #   Increase security in case of attack attempt
  swarm_socket:
    image: alpine/socat
    command: tcp-listen:2375,fork,reuseaddr unix-connect:/var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - net_mgmt
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
          - node.platform.os == linux

  # swarm_kv
  #   Key/Value store for traefik cluster
  swarm_kv:
    image: consul
    command: agent -server -client='{{ GetInterfaceIP "eth0" }}' -bind='{{ GetInterfaceIP "eth0" }}' -bootstrap
    volumes:
      - swarm_kv_data:/consul/data
    networks:
      - net_mgmt
    deploy:
      mode: global
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        failure_action: rollback
        delay: 30s
        monitor: 15s
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 10
        window: 60s
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
          - node.platform.os == linux

  # traefik_init
  #   Init traefik config
  traefik_init:
    image: traefik:1.7
    depends_on:
      - swarm_socket
    command:
      - "storeconfig"
      - "--logLevel=DEBUG"
      - "--api"
      - "--entrypoints=Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https"
      - "--entrypoints=Name:https Address::443 TLS"
      - "--defaultentrypoints=http,https"
      - "--acme"
      - "--acme.storage=traefik/acme/account"
      - "--acme.entryPoint=https"
      - "--acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint=http"
      - "--acme.onHostRule=true"
      - "--acme.onDemand=false"
      - "--acme.acmeLogging=true"
      - "--acme.email=mail@example.com" # Set your email
      - "--docker"
      - "--docker.swarmmode=true"
      - "--docker.endpoint=tcp://swarm_socket:2375"
      - "--docker.watch=true"
      - "--docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--docker.domain=example.com" # Set your domain
      - "--consul"
      - "--consul.endpoint=swarm_kv:8500"
      - "--consul.prefix=traefik"
    networks:
      - net_mgmt
      - net_public
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
          - node.platform.os == linux

  # traefik
  #   Traefik cluster
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.7
    depends_on:
      - swarm_socket
      - traefik_init
    command:
      - "--docker"
      - "--docker.swarmmode=true"
      - "--docker.endpoint=tcp://swarm_socket:2375"
      - "--consul"
      - "--consul.endpoint=swarm_kv:8500"
      - "--consul.prefix=traefik"
    networks:
      - net_mgmt
      - net_public
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080 # Remove after that config works
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.port=8080"
        - "traefik.docker.network=net_public"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.example.com" # Set you domain
        - "traefik.frontend.auth.basic.users=[sgobbit:$apr1$hpnuX1jh$IXu2P4aae0weviroUxP4S1]"
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.platform.os == linux

  # catchall
  #   Catch all unmanaged domain and show a dedicated page
  catchall:
    image: mikesir87/cats # Replace with real static page
    networks:
      - net_public
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.port=5000"
        - "traefik.protocol=http"
        - "traefik.backend=catchall"
        - "traefik.docker.network=net_public"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=HostRegexp:{catchall:.*}"
        - "traefik.frontend.priority=2"
        - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"
        - "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.swarm=true"
        - "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.method=drr"
        - "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.stickiness=true"
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.platform.os == linux

  # portainer_agent
  #   Agent that run on all nodes
  portainer_agent:
    image: portainer/agent
    environment:
      AGENT_CLUSTER_ADDR: tasks.portainer_agent
      AGENT_PORT: 9001
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes:/var/lib/docker/volumes
    networks:
      - net_mgmt
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.platform.os == linux

  # portainer
  #   Web UI to manage the cluster
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    depends_on:
      - portainer_agent
    command: -H tcp://tasks.portainer_agent:9001 --tlsskipverify
    volumes:
      - portainer_data:/data
    networks:
      - net_mgmt
      - net_public
    ports: # Remove after that config works
      - 9000:9000 # Remove after that config works
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.port=9000"
      - "traefik.docker.network=net_public"
      - "traefik.backend=portainer"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:portainer.example.com" # Set you domain
      - "traefik.frontend.priority=1"
      - "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.swarm=true"
      - "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.method=drr"
      - "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.stickiness=true"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
          - node.platform.os == linux

volumes:
  swarm_kv_data: # Storage Key/Value
  portainer_data: # Storage portainer

networks:
  net_mgmt:
    driver: overlay
    external: true
  net_public:
    driver: overlay
    external: true
```

Comment: You've got a lot going on in your example stack file there, so it's hard to create a single answer to this question. The best thing to do on SO is narrow this down to just a single question and a specific example with just the minimum config which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Traefik docs say](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/) to enable acme logging for Let's Encrypt info: `acmeLogging = true`
2. Check out my Swarm example of Portainer plus Traefik plus more at http://dogvs.cat
3. Use Swarm raft log rather then consul for traefik? No, it's not possible as an end user.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply and of course for your repo on github.

I have make many attempts, but something goes wrong when i use consul, because i loose and don't get again certificates for my domains.

I also have try to deploy your example stack-proxy-global.yml and stack-portainer.yml, with little changes to volumes and i also have uncomment acme section, but i get same issue.

Have you tested letsencrypt + traefik + swarm + consul?

I also have trying to look at logs, but i don't see acme related errors.

Comment: Yes I use that setup all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I had not reported it yet, but I had found the reason why Portainer was not reachable, in my deploy file the "labels" section was out of the "deploy" section where it should instead be inserted.

But the problem with "Let's Encrypt" persists when I'm working with "Consul".

I added these lines to the "traefik_init" service commands:

```
  - --traefikLog
  - --traefikLog.filePath=/logs/traefik.log
  - --traefikLog.format=json
  - --accessLog
  - --accessLog.filePath=/logs/access.log
  - --accessLog.format=json
```

And this volume to the traefik container:

```
volumes:
  - /home/dockers/traefik:/logs
```

And I was able to verify the log better, i see these error, but i can't know how to solve:

```
time="2019-01-06T12:12:19Z" level=debug msg="Building ACME client..."
time="2019-01-06T12:12:19Z" level=error msg="Cannot unmarshall private key []"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:19Z" level=error msg="Error building ACME client &{Email: Registration:<nil> PrivateKey:[] KeyType: DomainsCertificate:{Certs:[] lock:{w:{state:0 sema:0} writerSem:0 readerSem:0 readerCount:0 readerWait:0}} ChallengeCerts:map[] HTTPChallenge:map[]}: private key was nil"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:19Z" level=debug msg="Cannot get key traefik/alias Key not found in store, setting default traefik"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:19Z" level=debug msg="Cannot get key traefik/alias Key not found in store, setting default traefik"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:19Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/backends/\": Key not found in store"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:19Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/frontends/\": Key not found in store"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:19Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/tls/\": Key not found in store"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:19Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider consul: {}"
```

...and...

```
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Datastore reload"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Cannot get key traefik/alias Key not found in store, setting default traefik"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Transaction committed be38f149-90f9-4e44-bf6c-34a714e243ce"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="LoadCertificateForDomains [traefik.digilogico.com]..."
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Datastore reload"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Looking for provided certificate to validate [traefik.digilogico.com]..."
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Domains [\"traefik.digilogico.com\"] need ACME certificates generation for domains \"traefik.digilogico.com\"."
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Loading ACME certificates [traefik.digilogico.com]..."
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=info msg="legolog: [INFO] [traefik.digilogico.com] acme: Obtaining bundled SAN certificate"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/backends/\": Key not found in store"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/frontends/\": Key not found in store"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/tls/\": Key not found in store"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider consul: {}"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=info msg="Skipping same configuration for provider consul"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Cannot get key traefik/alias Key not found in store, setting default traefik"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/backends/\": Key not found in store"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/frontends/\": Key not found in store"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/tls/\": Key not found in store"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider consul: {}"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=info msg="Skipping same configuration for provider consul"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Cannot get key traefik/alias Key not found in store, setting default traefik"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/backends/\": Key not found in store"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/frontends/\": Key not found in store"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Cannot list keys under \"traefik/tls/\": Key not found in store"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider consul: {}"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:57Z" level=info msg="Skipping same configuration for provider consul"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:58Z" level=info msg="legolog: [INFO] [traefik.digilogico.com] AuthURL: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz/dLo1YvzenunzLIIqFAmtuQftWZaRefPmYKfgv4-N0c4"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:58Z" level=info msg="legolog: [INFO] [traefik.digilogico.com] acme: Trying to solve HTTP-01"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:58Z" level=debug msg="Challenge Present traefik.digilogico.com"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:58Z" level=debug msg="Transaction 65fbd48b-b7d8-4f8a-b4e7-c8bff46833a5 begins"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:58Z" level=error msg="Datastore sync error: object lock value: expected 65fbd48b-b7d8-4f8a-b4e7-c8bff46833a5, got be38f149-90f9-4e44-bf6c-34a714e243ce, retrying in 532.564811ms"
time="2019-01-06T12:12:58Z" level=debug msg="Datastore reload"
```